# Need city/state snippet for contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

My PHP contact form is working correctly and outputs all info including senders IP address in the subsequent e-mail. I'm having trouble coding the PHP form to also receive the sender's city and state in the email that the form generates.

I've tried several code snippets, but the most I get is the city and state output on the web page above the form.  I need it in the email instead.  Looking for a free service.

**PHP form**

```
<?php
include 'contact_config.php';
session_start();
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
include 'functions.php';

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$level = stripslashes($_POST['level']);
$age = stripslashes($_POST['age']);
$drums = stripslashes($_POST['drums']);
$referral = stripslashes($_POST['referral']);
$city = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
$subject = " Website Inquiry";
$message = "

Name:  ".$_POST['name']
."

E-mail Address:  ".$_POST['email']
."

Level:  ".$_POST['level']
."

Age:  ".$_POST['age']
."

Drums:  ".$_POST['drums']
."

Referral:  ".$_POST['referral']
."

Message:  ".$_POST['content']
."

City:  ".$_POST['city']
."

IP Address:  ". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$error = '';

// Check name

if(!$name)
{
$error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
}

// Check email

if(!$email)
{
$error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
}

if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
{
$error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
}

if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) && strtolower($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) != strtolower($_POST['captcha']))
{
$error .= "Incorrect captcha numbers.<br />";
}

if(!$error)
{

$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
 "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Use `$city`, not `$_POST['city']`, no? If you can output it you should be able to send it.

Comment: _" Looking for a free service."_ Wrong place then, we aren't a free coding service.

Comment: Stackoverflow coders offered help with this issue discussing both free and paid location services.  However, most all posts sent the location output to the webpage containing the form and not the email generated by the form.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code:

```
$message = "

Name:  ".$_POST['name']
."

E-mail Address:  ".$_POST['email']
."

Level:  ".$_POST['level']
."

Age:  ".$_POST['age']
."

Drums:  ".$_POST['drums']
."

Referral:  ".$_POST['referral']
."

Message:  ".$_POST['content']
."

City:  ".$_POST['city']
."

IP Address:  ". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

You are concatting Variables to a new Variable. Just add $_POST['state'] or how you called these fields, to this large Variable. Because you already added $_POST['city'].

So if it is not showing in the email, the Fields you are sending, are named differently.

Comment: Do you mean?

City:  ".$_POST['city']
."
State:  ".$_POST['state']
."

Comment: This should do the trick, but only if city and state are submitted by POST and are not generated, manipulated or changed somewhere else.

Comment: Is this correct as well?

$city = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));

or do I need to change that?

Comment: My email is showing this:

City:  

State:  

IP Address:  65.8.161.226

City and state are blank...ip address is correct.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seems like $_POST['city'] and $_POST['state'] are empty. Doublecheck if in your html formular the fields have exactly the same name, as the once here inside the brackets

Comment: I assumed that I didn't need an html field for the city as I didn't need one for the ip address.

Comment: $_POST['something'] ALWAYS means, that you send data from somewhere per POST to somewhere else. 
if you get the city and state based on sth else, then a user input, you should not write $_POST['city'] and $_POST['state'].
Instead do whatever you do to get the data, save them in variables like $city and $state, and then City: ".$city ." State: ".$state ."

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  However your suggestion didn't work.  I'll keep trying to fiddle.